curlを用いたGitlabへのファイルアップロード方法
curlを使用してGitlabのあるプロジェクトにおける特定のディレクトリにローカルからファイルをアップロードしたいです。
どのようなコマンドにすればよいでしょうか。

この辺の記事 Uploading a file to the gitlab package registry,How to push to package registry of personal Gitlab project? を見ると仕様のドキュメントサイトに書かれているようですので調べてみてはどうでしょう？ GitLab Generic Packages Repository, REST API あと日本語に翻訳して公開されているサイトがこちらのようです。GitLab日本語マニュアル

git コマンドを使わないのは、何か理由がありますか？
